# Very Odd Right-Click Behaviour on MBP 16

Tags: macbook-pro, magic-trackpad, contextual-menu, gesture

**MBP 16
Catalina 10.15.5**

**Problem "Odd Behaviour"**

1. Right-click (2-finger tap on trackpad) URL or text.
2. Whole URL is auto-highlighted and auto-selected (see image below):
   [image]
3. When I click "Open Link in a New Tab", the auto-highlight does not release.
4. I will need to left-click twice in an empty space to release it.
5. I have tried this on Safari, Chrome and Edge.
6. However, if I right-click slightly above or below the link text, the it acts normally without anything being auto-highlighted or auto-selected (see image below).
   [image]
7. This is system-wide (TextEdit, Office apps, Affinity apps), for normal text where simply right-clicking auto-selects the word, where previously I had to three-finger drag or double-click on the word to select it.
8. The same thing happens when I Control + Click.
9. Same thing happens when I use my USB mouse to directly right-click (was never used or connected for a whole week before I had to test this behaviour).

**Events within 6 hours prior to me noticing this**

1. I installed the Tidal app.
2. I installed new fonts directly to FontBook (which was validated).
3. I connected and disconnected my bluetooth headphone.
4. A Chromium extension auto-updated.
5. Primarily on Youtube and Netflix.

**What I've tried**

1. Safe mode - same behaviour.
2. Toggling different settings for Trackpad.
3. Checked Accessibility

*I'm not sure what triggered this and need to disable or stop this behaviour.*

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. For the record: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Right-clicking (mouse, trackpad, Control-click) always highlights the link, even if I right-click slightly above or below the link.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I asked a friend to do the same and he gave me the same answer as you. I might be experiencing a very bad case of Mandela Effect if not for the behaviour being odder in Youtube where sometimes after I open a video in a new tab, everything is selected when I click that tab - similar to how it would appear if someone hits Cmd+A in that page.

Comment: Everything except 6 is expected behaviour. I cannot repro 6.  If you really don't want the highlight, you could Cmd/click instead [or Shift/Cmd/click to bring the new tab to the front too.]